# Implementing dry-run in bash scripts

Tags: bash

How would one implement a dry-run option in a bash script?

I can think of either wrapping every single command in an if and echoing out the command instead of running it if the script is running with dry-run.

Another way would be to define a function and then passing each command call through that function.

Something like:

```
function _run () {
    if [[ "$DRY_RUN" ]]; then
        echo $@
    else
        $@
    fi
}

`_run mv /tmp/file /tmp/file2`

`DRY_RUN=true _run mv /tmp/file /tmp/file2`
```

Is this just wrong and there is a much better way of doing it?

Comment: So, you want to print what the command will do (including the values of the $VARIABLES) without actually executing the command. I use something like your `_run()` function, sometimes with 'set -xv', but I would love a better way.

Comment: yeah, exactly that. I'm wondering if there isn't an internal variable you can set in bash so commands don't actually execute, instead of passing them through a function

Comment: There's no reason that this question should have been marked community wiki.

Comment: Bash is a shell. There is no reason for it to do dry runs. I don't think there is a better way of doing it than you've already done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [BashFAQ/050: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for a discussion of this subject.

Although now removed, the section [How to add testing capability to a programs](https://web.archive.org/web/20100526030004/http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#How_to_add_testing_capability_to_a_programs) may still be useful.

Comment: Not an alternative, but it looks like an excellent resource for testing and working with longer bash programs.

Comment: I rolled back the edit that added an anchor to a particular part of the linked page since the point of my answer, as stated, is to read the discussion as a whole rather than point to one specific how-to portion. The point of the linked page is generally to try to avoid putting commands to be executed into variables since there are a lot of gotchas.

Comment: It would be far more useful if this answer summarised the salient points of this article. One line answers are still poor answers.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to play with the answer from @Dennis Williamson's. Here's what I got:

```
Run () {
    if [ "$TEST" ]; then
        echo "$*"
        return 0
    fi

    eval "$@"
}
```

The `eval "$@"` is important here, and is better then simply doing `$*`. `$@` returns all parameters and `$*` returns all parameters with no whitespace/quoting.

```
$ mkdir dir
$ touch dir/file1 dir/file2
$ FOO="dir/*"
$ TEST=true Run ls -l $FOO
ls -l dir/file1 dir/file2
$ Run ls -l $FOO
-rw-r--r--  1 stefanl  stefanl  0 Jun  2 21:06 dir/file1
-rw-r--r--  1 stefanl  stefanl  0 Jun  2 21:06 dir/file2
```